# Behavior when set two multidimensional arrays equal

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently programming a Tetris application. I'm using a multidimensional integer array for my stones, which represent their position on the multidimensional Panel field (int[row][colum]).

I'm now at the point, where I want to update my field colors, when a stone has moved down. Instead of looping all the fields and all the tetris stones, I want to just update the current stone, so I added a variable for the last position. 
But I get some problems with setting this variable!

My question now is, why does this work:

```
public void moveDown()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < location.Length; i++)
    {
        last_location[i][0] = location[i][0];
        last_location[i][1] = location[i][1];
        location[i][0] += 1;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
public void moveDown()
{
    last_location = location;
    for (int i = 0; i < location.Length; i++)
    {
        location[i][0] += 1;
    }
    //last_location got also updated??
}
```

The problem here is, that after the loop, the last_location hast the exact same values as the location variable, which changes **afterwards**!
Why? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type are `last_location` and `location`? `int[][]`?

Comment: Yes, they're both int[ ][ ]!

Comment: You've given `last_location` a reference to `location`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array is a *reference* type.

Because of that, when you write `last_location = location;`, **you do not create a copy of the array**. `last_location` uses the same instance of the array than `location`.

So when you modify one of the two variables, the same unique instance in modified in memory.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now :)
Is there a way, to create a copy while telling not to add a reference? (Without doing this loop?)

Comment: @Yami, I've added a copy example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In second example you assign the reference, meanwhile in first one you assign the value.

When you do **last_location = location;** you assign your variable **last_location** the pointer to your location, so when you change location value, because last_location point on **location**, it seems to you that these its values are also change. Both **last_location** and **location** points on *single memory partition*.

In first case **last_location[i][0] = location[i][0]** you assign values in the loop, not referrences, so your **last_location** and **location** point on *different memory partitions* with different values.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `last_location` to the object referenced by `location`,

```
last_location = location;
```

you then have two references to the same object. The object that was referenced by `last_location` is no longer referenced and will be garbage collected in due course.

---

The quickest way to achieve what you want is to intialize `last_location` to the same dimensions as `location` and use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx),

For example,

```
var location = new []
    {
        new int[10],
        new int[10]
    };

var last_location = new []
    {
        new int[10],
        new int[10]
    };

Buffer.BlockCopy(location, 0, last_location, 0, location.Length * sizeof(int));
```